# Quartus D Flip Flop with asynchronous reset

Tags: flip-flop, quartus

I need a DFF with asynchronous reset in my diagram. Does quartus have it? If not, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am very new to quartus and that's why I didn't know it. But I post the answer for people similar to me:
Use LPM_DFF and the aclr port will be your active high asynchronous reset.